# Refresh a ng-repeat list from server every x seconds

Tags: javascript, angularjs

As the title suggests I want to be able to refresh a ng-repeat list from the server every 30 seconds or so. More data can be added on the backend, so I want my list to reflect that. Right now I have the regular `$http.get( )` working fine which is here:

```
$scope.select = function() {
  $scope.searchText = '';
  $scope.selectedItem = null;
  var url = 'http:xxxxxxxxxxxx.com';
  url += $scope.selectModel.name;
  console.debug("GOING TO: " + url);
  $http.get(url).success(function(data2) {
    $scope.records = [];
    data2.forEach(function(r) {
        $scope.records.push(r);
    });
  });
};
```

and the portion of the web page it supplies is:

```
<div style="margin: 1em">
<h4>Search</h4>
        <div role="form">
            <!-- start dropdown -->
            <div class="form-group">
                <select class="form-control" ng-options="model as model.name for model in allModels" ng-model="selectModel" ng-change="select()">
                    <option value="">Choose Model</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <!-- /end dropdown-->
            <div class="form-group">
                <input id="start_date" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Threat Date">
            </div>
        </div>
    <div>
        <table class="table table-hover table-striped" ng-show="records">
            <thead>
                <th>#</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Score</th>
            </thead>
            <tr data-ng-repeat=" item in records | orderBy : '-score' | limitTo : 10 " ng-click="moreInfo(item)">
                <td>{{$index+1}}</td>
                <td>{{item.name.slice(5)}}</td>
                <td>{{item.score.toFixed(3)}}</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Is there a way to choose a time @ which the list will refresh? And it has to be without hitting a refresh button or something like that. Thanks in advance.

**EDIT** This is the error I get when I try and use `$interval` as suggested:

```
ReferenceError: $interval is not defined
    at Scope.$scope.select (http:xxxxxxxxxx.com/UserQuery/js/script.js:24:7)
    at fn (eval at <anonymous> (https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.0-rc.0/angular.js:12822:15), <anonymous>:2:209)
    at Scope.$get.Scope.$eval (https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.0-rc.0/angular.js:15465:28)
    at https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.0-rc.0/angular.js:21825:13
    at https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.0-rc.0/angular.js:24485:9
    at forEach (https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.0-rc.0/angular.js:332:20)
    at NgModelController.$$writeModelToScope (https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.0-rc.0/angular.js:24483:5)
    at writeToModelIfNeeded (https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.0-rc.0/angular.js:24476:14)
    at https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.0-rc.0/angular.js:24470:9
    at validationDone (https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.0-rc.0/angular.js:24398:9)
```

**SOLUTION** With combined efforts from this and another question, I came to a solution. First off, like many on this question mentioned, the key here is the use of `$interval`. There are a few important things to not about using it though.

- It must be included in the dependencies for the controller as
  @mcpDESIGNS mentioned.
- In my case, where there is a dropdown therefor multiple things I want
  to `$interval` over, it is important to close one when you open a new
  one.

  ```
  $scope.select = function() {
        $scope.searchText = '';
        $scope.selectedItem = null;
        $interval.cancel(mainInterval);
        $scope.url = '';
        url = 'http:xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.com';
        url += $scope.selectModel.name;
        console.debug("GOING TO: " + url);
        $http.get(url).success(function(data2) {
          $scope.records = [];
          data2.forEach(function(r) {
            $scope.records.push(r);
          });
        });     
        mainInterval = $interval(function() {
          console.debug("UPDATING....");
          console.debug("GETTING NEW FROM " + url);
          $http.get(url).success(function(data2) {
            $scope.records = [];
            data2.forEach(function(r) {
              $scope.records.push(r);
            });
          });
        }, 5000);
      };
  ```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at this:

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interval

It wraps JavaScript's native setInterval function. You can set it to do the poll every 30 seconds.

It also returns a promise so you can cancel the interval when required.

However, please bear this in mind:

"*Intervals created by this service must be explicitly destroyed when you are finished with them. In particular they are not automatically destroyed when a controller's scope or a directive's element are destroyed. You should take this into consideration and make sure to always cancel the interval at the appropriate moment. See the example below for more details on how and when to do this."*

**EDIT**

Taking your code:

```
$scope.select = function() {
  $scope.searchText = '';
  $scope.selectedItem = null;
  var url = 'http:xxxxxxxxxxxx.com';
  url += $scope.selectModel.name;
  console.debug("GOING TO: " + url);
  $http.get(url).success(function(data2) {
    $scope.records = [];
    data2.forEach(function(r) {
        $scope.records.push(r);
    });
  });
};
```

Try changing to this:

```
    $scope.select = function() {
      $scope.searchText = '';
      $scope.selectedItem = null;
      var url = 'http:xxxxxxxxxxxx.com';
      url += $scope.selectModel.name;
      console.debug("GOING TO: " + url);
      $http.get(url).success(function(data2) {
        $scope.records = [];
        data2.forEach(function(r) {
            $scope.records.push(r);
        });
      });
      $interval(function() {
        $http.get(url).success(function(data2) {
        $scope.records = [];
        data2.forEach(function(r) {
            $scope.records.push(r);
        });
      });
    }, 30000);
};
```

If that works you can then refactor the actual $http.get out into a named function to remove the code smell.

Comment: Hey since the guy above wont answer, the js method I call with the `$http.get( )` is something that I call based on certain events. Will having the `$interval` inside of that have an affect on the initial call. In order to populate the list the first time the user has to call the `select` method. and after that Is where I want the list to refresh. I dont want to have to call the `select` method every time to refresh.

Comment: I was thinking about this, if you put the $interval inside the initial $http call you should be ok.

Comment: Hey thanks, for the patience, but I am still having trouble even after you code. I updated the OP with the error message regarding `$interval`. I out console outs in there and it isn't even getting inside of the `$interval`

Comment: Thanks, I did get it working thanks to @mcpDesigns pointed out I need to include it as a dependency on the controller. Though obviously your code helped. +1 m8. Thanks for being patient.

Comment: Hey one last quick question if it doesn't kill you to help. In my code, `selectModel.name` is a value that is selected from a dropdown. When I use what you provided and select one thing, the refresh works perfect. But when I select another thing, the refresh will do one then the other @ the designated interval. Any ideas? Should I null something out?

Comment: Right, inbetween eating fajitas, the first thing that springs to mind is.....can you make `var url` into a $scope variable so Angular keeps track of changes to it?

Comment: That kind of does. But the way the interval method is placed, everytime I call select it is like there is a new thread going on. Say I choose option 1 from dropdown. Then option 2. Before you helped me it was like list for option 1, list for option 2, each, every 5 seconds. Then when you provided a solution, its now like option 1, option1, every 5 seconds. So it stays on the correct option now, but just spits it out as many times as I select it. I think `$interval` needs to be somewhere else. I will start another question tho. Thanks for the help.

Comment: YES! That's it! $Interval will spawn a new "thread" (not really a thread) each time. Gimme a few mins to knock together a sample.....

Comment: Cool thanks. And sorry thats the best way I knew to explain it. I just started with angular within the last week :p

Answer (score 2):

Just use a `$interval()` around your `$http` to make it refresh every 30 seconds.

```
$interval(function () {
    $http({ 
        /* run your AJAX and update your $scope / etc */ 
    });
}, 30000); // in milliseconds
```

> Note: `$interval` must be dependency injected into your controller / service / etc to work!

```
 // for examples sake
.controller('MyController', ['$interval', function ($interval) { }]);
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. Does putting it inside this interval not allow for the initial call to happen?

Comment: You can always put that call into a function and then include that function in the `$interval`

Comment: There is no reason this shouldn't work.  Just call your select function from your interval.  Also, make sure you are properly injecting the $interval service.

Comment: @user1518802. So you are saying just put the `$interval` outside of everything else, then inside of it just call `select();`?

Comment: Yes, $interval is a stand alone service that will operate by itself.  So every 30 seconds, it will call your select function which builds your Url and everything else.

Answer (score 0):

Use **ng-table** instead.
Have a look http://bazalt-cms.com/ng-table/

And u can call its **reload** propery, which will refresh your table,

The reload you can call inside $timeout service provided by angular.

```
$timeout(function(){
tablename.reload();
},3000);
```

**or**

Just call the select function inside the timeout

```
$timeout(function(){
$scope.select();
},3000);
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, though I don't really want to add stuff to the project

Comment: okay,what if you just call the select function inside timeout  $timeout(function(){ $scope.select()},3000);

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
Ok, I think the plan is each time select is fired, the existing interval needs to be cancelled and another one started. Have a look at this:

```
   var intervalObj;
   $scope.select = function() {
      if (intervalObj !== null) {
          $interval.cancel(intervalObj);
          intervalObj = null;
      }
      $scope.searchText = '';
      $scope.selectedItem = null;
      var url = 'http:xxxxxxxxxxxx.com';
      url += $scope.selectModel.name;
      console.debug("GOING TO: " + url);
      $http.get(url).success(function(data2) {
        $scope.records = [];
        data2.forEach(function(r) {
            $scope.records.push(r);
        });
      });
      intervalObj = $interval(function() {
        $http.get(url).success(function(data2) {
        $scope.records = [];
        data2.forEach(function(r) {
            $scope.records.push(r);
        });
      });
    }, 30000);
};
```

I have not been able to fully test this, but the principle is sound.

Comment: Oh man, now the `$interval` portion doesn't work. I think it just cancels the whole `$interval`. Worth a try though. Thanks m8.

Comment: Updated op with solution. This one was the closest, but tweaked a bit :)